# Get file extension after file is uploaded and moved in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6, symfony-http-foundation

I'm uploading a file through Symfony2 and I am trying to rename original in order to avoid override the same file. This is what I am doing:

```
$uploadedFile = $request->files;
$uploadPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/uploads/';

try {
    $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->move($uploadPath, $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getClientOriginalName());
} catch (\ Exception $e) {
    // set error 'can not upload avatar file'
}

// this get right filename
$avatarName = $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
// this get wrong extension meaning empty, why? 
$avatarExt = $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getExtension();

$resource = fopen($uploadPath . $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getClientOriginalName(), 'r');
unlink($uploadPath . $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getClientOriginalName());
```

I am renaming file as follow:

```
$avatarName = sptrinf("%s.%s", uniqid(), $uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getExtension());
```

But `$uploadedFile->get('avatar')->getExtension()` is not giving me the extension of the uploaded file so I give a wrong filename like `jdsfhnhjsdf.` without extension, Why? What is the right way to rename file after or before move to the end path? Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the solution is really simple if you know it.

Since you `move`d the `UploadedFile`, the current object instance cannot be used anymore. The file no longer exists, and so the `getExtension` will return in `null`. The new file instance is returned from the `move`.

Change your code to (refactored for clarity):

```
    $uploadPath = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../web/uploads/';

    try {
        $uploadedAvatarFile = $request->files->get('avatar');

        /* @var $avatarFile \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File */
        $avatarFile = $uploadedAvatarFile->move($uploadPath, $uploadedAvatarFile->getClientOriginalName());

        unset($uploadedAvatarFile);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        /* if you don't set $avatarFile to a default file here
         * you cannot execute the next instruction.
         */
    }

    $avatarName = $avatarFile->getBasename();
    $avatarExt = $avatarFile->getExtension();

    $openFile = $avatarFile->openFile('r');
    while (! $openFile->eof()) {
        $line = $openFile->fgets();
        // do something here...
    }
    // close the file
    unset($openFile);
    unlink($avatarFile->getRealPath());
```

(Code not tested, just wrote it) Hope it helps!

Comment: Just one thing that I don't know why happen: `Warning: fclose(): 78 is not a valid stream resource` otherwise works perfectly

Comment: Strange, since `fopen` return a resource on success and `FALSE` on failure. Maybe the file is already closed, so php triggers a warning?

Comment: Also note that a symfony `File` is a subtype of `SplFileInfo` so can just use `$avatarFile->openFile('r')`.... I'll update my answer to show you the "proper" way